# О наречии "все"

Tags: морфология

Непонятно, какой логикой руководствуются авторы словарей при разграничении **частицы **"всё"** и наречия **"всё"**.**

---

Определить ту или иную часть речи помогает подбор синонима той же части речи, но как в качестве синонима может подбираться слово другой части речи?

---

Что я имею в виду:

> Это **всё** вы виноваты! (наречие, синонимично "только", "исключительно", именно")

Все три слова являются частицами, но при этом считаем "всё" наречием. Еще более непонятно, какой вопрос и от чего они собрались задавать к этому "всё"? У меня он, например, не задается, для меня здесь "всё" является обычной частицей.

---

Другая сторона медали:

> Я принялся ее рассматривать, сперва украдкой, потом **всё** смелее и смелее.

В данном случае "всё" синонимично "**еще**", но почему-то авторы относят слово к частице. Здесь как раз задается логичный вопрос: смелее (насколько) еще, смелее (насколько) всё.

---

К слову, в БАС это значение присвоено наречию (с чем я полностью согласен):

> В сочетании со сравнительной степенью прилагательных и наречий указывает на постепенное усиление, нарастание качества: ***все*** мрачней и ниже
> тучи опускаются над морем...

---

В чем логика?

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на БАС? Потому что странно, в МАС это же значение присвоено частице.

Comment: @Серж file:///C:/Users/milmo/AppData/Local/Temp/Rar$DIb13812.118/%D0%91%D0%90%D0%A1_02_%D0%92.pdf

Comment: Не открывается ссылка.

Comment: @Серж Тут уж я не могу помочь.

Comment: А вы для прикола дали адрес файла на вашем ПК?

Comment: @oleedd другой возможности у меня нет!

Comment: Это всё равно что попросить кого-то открыть файл на вашем компьютере, находясь не у вас. Вы дали адрес расположения файла на своём диске C! Это так не работает, нельзя так просто смотреть файлы на вашем компьютере через Интернет, смешно получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить о слове ‟всё” в таком предложении: ‟В этом фильме мне понравилось всё”, то здесь ‟всё” является местоимением, а не наречием (местоименные наречия не изменяются по формам в отличии от слова ‟всё”).

По поводу предложения: ‟Я принялся ее рассматривать, сперва украдкой, потом всё смелее и смелее”. Взгляните на предложение: ‟Я двигался быстрее”. Можно заметить, что оно не имеет смысла без ‟всё” – ‟Я двигался всё быстрее”. Это слово выполняет здесь специфическую грамматическую функцию: сочетание этого слова с прилагательным в сравнительной степени обозначает постепенное изменение. Все подобные слова со специфическими грамматическими функциями следует просто считать частицами. И да, ‟ещё” здесь не синонимично.

По поводу предложения: ‟Это всё ты виноват!”. Если бы предложение было такое: ‟Это всё твоя вина”, то тут было бы всё очевидно: ‟Это” – указательное местоимение, а ‟всё” – местоимение и подлежащее. Но в предложении: ‟Это всё ты виноват” – не очень понятно, что там чем является. Здесь ‟это” – это уже указательная частица. Вот здесь я не знаю, и даже думать об этом не хочется, поэтому здесь ничем помочь не могу.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146447/discussion-on-answer-by-rumpelstiltskin---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.